# BigQuery splitting a row into multiple columns

Tags: sql, split, google-bigquery

I have a table that stores logs into one row. I have unnested it and one example row looks like this:

TestObserver(2) TestFragment(1) TestView(1) TestNotifications(2) TestActivity(1) and so on.

I would like to conveert TestObserver, TestFragment and so on into columns and its values (2), (1), etc into its rows. There are plenty of these Test logs, it is not a fixated number of them. There is no delimiter between them. I would also like to SUM each TestObserver, TestFragment and so on values found in each row.

How can I achieve this?

I tried trimming and splitting but the result is not what it is expected.

Comment: Try to get a bit clarification here. is there always exactly a space between each term?  Such as TestObserver(2)[SPACE]TestFragment(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume there is no consistent delimiter(not even a space) between terms in your log, we can still get your desired results by using [REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) function and [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) operator in BigQuery.

Step 1. Use [regex_replace()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace) to move all spaces in the log

step 2. Use [REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) to fetch each (term(quantity)) token into an array.

Step 3. [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) the array to one (term(quantity)) token per row

Step 4. Use [regex_extract()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) to fetch term and quantity separately. Please, we need to use [negative lookaround regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)(?= and ?<=) to get the exact data we need for term and quantity.

Step 5. Group by term and sum() on quantity to get the result.

See the following code as example:

```
WITH log_extracted AS (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(
        'TestObserver(2) TestFragment(1) TestView(1) TestNotifications(2) TestActivity(1)',
        '_',
        ''
      ),
      '\w+\(\d+\)'
    ) AS log_tokens
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(log_token, '(\w+)(?=\(\d+\))') AS term,
  SUM(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(log_token, '(?<=\w\()\d+') AS INT64)) AS quantity
FROM log_extracted
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(log_tokens) AS log_token
GROUP BY
  1
```

example output:

| term | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| TestFragment | 1 |
| TestView | 1 |
| TestObserver | 2 |
| TestNotifications | 2 |
| TestActivity | 1 |